# Use two streamreaders at the same time for comparing and replacing columns and rows?

Tags: c#, streamreader

See, I'm coding a simple program to replace data in a CSV file.

What I need to replace is column 2 (parent) to set the name of the ID instead of ID, like this:

Original file:

```
ID    - PARENT - NAME
ID 1  -        - Name of ID 1
ID 2  -  ID 1  - Name of ID 2
ID 3  -  ID 2  - Name of ID 3
ID 4  -  ID 1  - Name of ID 4
ID 5  -  ID 4  - Name of ID 5
```

Result:

```
ID    - PARENT         - NAME
ID 1  -                - Name of ID 1
ID 2  -  Name of ID 1  - Name of ID 2
ID 3  -  Name of ID 2  - Name of ID 3
ID 4  -  Name of ID 1  - Name of ID 4
ID 5  -  Name of ID 4  - Name of ID 5
```

So I need to do a recursive loop here using two instances of the same StreamReader to compare each one. I'm not asking how to do the loop, but how to use two streamreaders at the same time, as I tried to do it by creating all the variables necessary but it seems C# won't accept that, and it just doesn't work, the data goes all blank... and doesn't give any errors either. How I can do it?

The part that works:

```
filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    fileContent = reader.ReadLine();
    int i = 1;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(nomArxiu, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
   {
      while (fileContent != null)
          {
              /// code to replace stuff, works for one single row at a time, but not for multiple rows at the same time
          }
   }
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
}
```

What I tried that doesn't work:

```
System.IO.StreamReader reader2 = reader; // create a copy of the reader object...
```

I want to have access to two independent stream readers of the same file, but it just doesn't work like this...

Comment: What's the maximum size of these CSVs? If they're small you could resort to a memory-intensive solution rather than a stream solution.

Comment: These CSVs can be quite large, many thousands of rows, thats why I'm coding this instead of replacing it manually.

Comment: Could you add the relevent parts of your code so we can understand what you've tried a bit better?

Comment: I added some code. With a single streamreader I have no problem, everything works, I can replace whatever I want but only working on one single row at the time, thats the problem, it's not enough with this.

Comment: `System.IO.StreamReader reader2 = reader;` wont clone `reader` into `reader2`, it will change its pointer to the pointer of `reader`, meaning `reader2` and `reader` are effectively the same object with the same stream position. What you want to do is create a brand new StreamReader. I'll see if I can format it into an answer.

Comment: Are you attempting to write over the same file, or to a new one?  Also, just use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to store each name associated with its ID so you can look it up.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Which is an `O(n)` solution too, instead of the `O(n2)` stream method. Although it doesn't scale well (`O(n)` memory, as opposed to `O(1)` with stream method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have with your code is that classes in C# are passed by reference, not by value.

This means that this line:

`System.IO.StreamReader reader2 = reader;`

...is *not* creating a new `StreamReader` as you had expected, but has created another reference to the same `StreamReader` with the same stream position.

What you need to do is create a new `StreamReader` with a new `FileStream` like so:

```
filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
var secondFileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(secondFileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    fileContent = reader.ReadLine();
    int i = 1;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(nomArxiu, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
    {
        while (fileContent != null)
        {
            /// code to replace stuff, works for one single row at a time, but not for multiple rows at the same time
        }
    }
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

---

I'm not sure of the functionality of running `OpenFileDialog.OpenFile()` twice, so if that doesn't work, try this:

```
filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (FileStream secondFileStream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(secondFileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    fileContent = reader.ReadLine();
    int i = 1;
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(nomArxiu, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
    {
        while (fileContent != null)
        {
            /// code to replace stuff, works for one single row at a time, but not for multiple rows at the same time
        }
    }
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Damn... That doesn't work. Error: file is used by another process (the first filestream) so cannot use a second one...

Comment: I've updated the second answer to include `FileShare.Read`. Try that and tell me if it works.